# "Que + presente de subjuntivo" – fórmula para expresar deseos

Tags: subjuntivo

Seguramente conocéis la combinación "que + presente de subjuntivo" que expresa deseos. Ya he encontrado algunos ejemplos para buenos deseos (*que tengas suerte, que tengas un buen día*, etc.) y ahora necesito un par de ejemplos para ilustrar „malos deseos“. La única expresión que conozco en español es „*que te den por ...*“ pero me da vergüenza decirlo delante de mi profe haciendo la presentación... ¿Hay algunas otras expresiones que expresan malos deseos  y que no suenen rudo?

Gracias

Comment: Que vayas al diablo.  (Bueno, tú no....)  Incluso parece que hay una canción.  La afinación no es lo que yo quisiera, pero el conjunto se oye bien.  https://youtu.be/lci03V5mqMI. // Ojalá que te mueras.  También tiene canción.  El video es de mal gusto pero el canto está bien.  https://youtu.be/byuMXm3MAho

Comment: Some examples here https://youtu.be/Vcv2e5UXclo?t=31s This is the "aterciopelados" adaptation of an old song and the lyrics says "Que te vaya bien/que te coja un carro/que te parta un rayo/que te espiche un tren///...que te muerda un perro/ que te lleve el diablo y marques calavera/. ... You can find the original song [here](http://www.albumcancionyletra.com/adios-que-te-vaya-bien_de_giolito-y-su-combo___265542.aspx). Showing this in your class could be good complement to your presentation.

Comment: Una canción más sutil al respecto es ["Que seas muy feliz"](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=alejandro+fernandez+ahora+que+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=SZhmWdp4jJHxB933k9gO), de Alejandro Fernández. Le dice ... "Que seas muy feliz... para que no regreses".

Comment: ¡muchísimas gracias a todos! =)

Answer (score 5):

Hay una [expresión de deseo negativo](https://diccionarioactual.com/que-te-gar%C3%BAe-finito/) muy pintoresca en el registro coloquial rioplatense (especialmente lo que se llama lunfardo, común en letras de tango), que quizá sea interesante llevar a una clase por lo curioso y metafórico:

> *Que te garúe finito*.

donde *garúe* es forma subjuntiva del verbo *garuar*, que proviene de *garúa*, "[llovizna](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llovizna)", y *finito* es diminutivo de *fino*, aquí con valor adverbial, con el significado de "ligero, pequeño". Vale decir: *garuar finito* significa "lloviznar ligeramente, con gotas pequeñas". Una garúa fina es obviamente muy molesta, por lo cual deseársela a alguien que se va es desearle un mal rato.

La expresión se utiliza para "dar por finalizada una conversación o un encuentro con alguien y despedirlo con un cierto tono despectivo". No es para nada cortés pero no contiene ninguna palabra malsonante.

Comment: Más allá de lo molesta que pueda ser una llovizna, podrás leer en la referencia que mencionas que en realidad se trata de un eufemismo: más que una llovizna, estamos deseando al otro una tormenta o un diluvio :)

Answer (score 4):

Aquí en España tenemos varias expresiones muy similares a la que mencionas ("que te den por el culo") que son versiones edulcoradas (más suaves):

> Que te den por el saco (en el lenguaje hablado suele eliminarse la partícula "el" quedando "que te den por saco" pero no sería correcto para la expresión escrita).

También:

> [Que te den morcilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PnBQhSF).

O, directamente:

> Que te den (posiblemente la más común en mi entorno).

También, como han indicado ya:

> Que te parta un rayo.

Todas ellas muestran desprecio por la persona con la que se habla y serían más o menos equivalentes al inglés *"fuck you"*.

Estoy seguro de que existen más. Actualizaré según me vayan viniendo a la mente.

Comment: ¡Hola J. Ruiz y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]! Esperamos leer muchas preguntas y respuestas tuyas.

Answer (score 3):

No es fácil encontrar ejemplos de malos deseos expresados con "que" + subjuntivo que no suenen de mal gusto, puesto que la estructura es coloquial y por lo tanto proclive a utilizarse para desearle lo peor al otro, con todo el sentimiento que eso conlleva:

- Que te **parta** un rayo.
- Cagado te **veas** y el agua lejos. (Alguna vez oí decir que es una maldición gitana.)
- Que te **vaya** para el culo/orto.

Todas estas expresiones también pueden introducirse con "ojalá".